# How do I reset user passwords in Xmail from the shell?

Tags: smtp

I have an old Xmail server running on a Gentoo Vmware box with full root access.I want to send a mail as user15 but can't remember the password.I have very basic Linux :( I am trying to reset the password for user15

[image]

I have tried entering say "user15" "XYZ" and saving the file but it does not work.

How do I successfully reset this Xmail user password when the server has no X server and no web admin.

**Update ls-l command on directory**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the xmail I think it is, you need to enter an encrypted string, not the actual password. You should be able to encrypt the password with a program called XMCrypt, usually located in `/var/MailRoot/bin`. You run it like this:

```
/var/MailRoot/bin/XMCrypt newpass
```

This will give you an encrypted string, e.g. `018c15646784`

You will need to stop xmail before editing the file. While you're at it, you probably want to fix the root password for the mail system (again, not the actual user root, just the xmail user!). That password lives in the file `ctrlaccounts.tab` and should be encrypted in the same way. Then start xmail back up

Now you have the fresh and shiny root password you can connect to the xmail console. It usually runs on port 6017. So telnet to that port and enter

```
root[TAB]mypass
```

where `[TAB]`is of course pressing the tab key. You should hopefully get a response ending in `OK`.

Now that you have a connection there are lots of things you can do from the console, e.g. change user passwords, or verify them. There's a lot of information at [this xmail howto](http://www.oocities.org/xmailearn/).

Comment: Hi, unfortunately the XMCrypt is not working says command not found even when I use the full path, also port 6017 appears to be down in NMap :(

Comment: The program may have been installed in another directory. Where did you find the mailusers.tab file?

Comment: /var/xmail/mailroot I can see the file /var/MailRoot/bin/XMCrypt but its listed as an ASCII with ls -l

Comment: Listed as an ASCII? Could you post the exact output from ls -l?

Comment: ok I have added that screenshot to my question.

Comment: The listing says it should be an executable file; ls doesn't normally tell you whether a file is ASCII or binary. But if it is some sort of script, the contents of the file would be interesting. If it says "command not found", it's probably trying to find a file that has been lost or uninstalled.

Comment: It does contain an ELF file header. would it be possible to send you my virtual machine as that might be easier?

Answer (score -1):

As root you should be able to run `passwd user15` to change the password.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the users listed here are Xmail users not users of the OS.